# Is there any way to stop Windows from prompting to scan a storage device that was incorrectly unmounted, other than by scanning it?

Tags: usb

From my understanding, if inserting a storage device into a Windows-based machine which wasn't previously unmounted properly, the "Scan and Fix" dialog is always presented to a user. Are there any other ways of stopping this dialog from appearing, other than by allowing Windows to scan it? Is there a way to remove the flag from the file system that Windows uses to determine whether it was improperly removed in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Procmon (or pslist?)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) while removing & reinserting same USB unsafely may give you the info of where that info is saved (likely registry). This may not be the simple solution you want, but a helpful tip so upvote if you find it helpful.

**--Edit**: [howtogeek.com indicates disabling a service can hide the prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35622/disable-scan-and-fix-for-removable-drives-in-windows/). 1)Open services.msc (as admin), double-click 'Shell Hardware Detection', change Startup type to disabled. 2)open msconfig (as admin), Services tab, untick 'Shell Hardware Detection'. However they advise it may be indicative of a filesystem or storage error/issue (rather than a flag remembering if it was unmounted badly as you say) so if you care about your storage I'd suggest running a test on it & safely remove.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. This flag is saved directly onto the filesystem of the device in question - I was just wondering if there was any way of clearing this flag other than by scanning.

Comment: Feel free to upvote since I work for those fake internet (rep) points :)